# Using SQL, can I show both total sum and partial sum in one table when grouped?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up a table which has date_trunc, partial sum, and total sum. This is my list:
(FYI dates in mm/dd/yyyy format)

**original_table columns are...**

```
my_date | task_name
01/01/2019 | task 1
01/02/2019 | task 2
01/05/2019 | task 3
02/01/2019 | task 4
02/05/2019 | task 5
03/01/2019 | task 6
03/04/2019 | task 7
03/07/2019 | task 8
03/09/2019 | task 9
...
```

I want this to look like the following:

```
group_month | sub_total | total
jan         | 3         | 9
feb         | 2         | 9
mar         | 4         | 9
```

I can only do this by using 2 tables, I am wondering if it is possible to do it with 1 table.

```
WITH total_table AS(
  SELECT 
    count(task_name) AS total_task
  FROM original_table
)
SELECT
   DATE_TRUNC('month',my_date) AS group_month,
   count(task_name) AS sub_total,
   total_task
FROM origianl_table, total_table
GROUP BY group_month
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below SQL:

```
select distinct extract('month' from my_date) mon_name,
count(*) over (partition by extract('month' from my_date)) sub_count,
count(*) over () total_count
from your_table
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/74617/11)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
   date_trunc('month', my_date) AS group_month,
   count(*) as sub_total,
   sum(count(*)) over() as total_task
from
    <original_table>
group by
    group_month
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately this returns 3 (there are 3 months) for all rows under total_task column, instead of 9 (there are total 9 tasks).